# is there alternate for sklearn import in intellij with airflow and docker

Tags: python, intellij-idea, scikit-learn, airflow, airflow-webserver

[attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY9T0.png)

I'm facing

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

in intellij as I'm using docker and airlfow to create a machine learning project eventhough I;ve installed package in the intellij and in docker container as well. Command I used to install in container

```
docker exec -it project_p-webserver-1  /bin/bash

pip install scikit-learn
```

and I've also locally installed sklearn from my terminal.

I tried installing the sklearn library in intellij, locally, docker container but nothing worked and error is still there as I'm using airflow for my machine learning model.

Comment: Did you install the package inside a running container? If so, please try installing it at build time via your Dockerfile.

Comment: Do not post text as image.

Comment: below is my docker file what should I write can please let me know in this comment box 
version: '3.7'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.6
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=airflow
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=airflow
      - POSTGRES_DB=airflow
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 10m
        max-file: "3"

  webserver:
    build: ./dockerfiles
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    environment:
      - LOAD_EX=n
      - EXECUTOR=Local
    logging:
      options:
        max-size: 10m
        max-file: "3"

Comment: the rest dockerfile content
volumes:
      - ./dags:/usr/local/airflow/dags
      - ./plugins:/usr/local/airflow/plugins
      - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    command: webserver
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ -f /usr/local/airflow/airflow-webserver.pid ]"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3